# Is there a way to create a listener in a Windows Form application for a custom protocol (URI Scheme)?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, url-scheme

I was able to create a URI Scheme in the Registry [HKCU\Software\Classes] for my VB.NET Windows Form application.

If I use the new URI [CSIPOS:] and then a string my application knows to open the application and read the arguments in the string.

The problem I'm having is if the application is already open and you use the same CSIPOS: link then nothing happens.

Is there a way to build a listener or a way to get the Custom Protocol URL to work while the application is open?

Comment: Whether you registered the Protocol in HKCU or HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, when an URI that specifies that Protocol is activated, the associated program that registered its path is executed. If your application is configured as single instance, you have to handle `StartupNextInstance` and see what you get there

Comment: Ok I tried OnStartupNextInstance and StartupNextInstance and neither show up as events I can handle in the form or the designer of the form.

Am I supposed to implement somewhere else?

Comment: You can override `OnStartupNextInstance` in the `ApplicationEvents.vb` file

Comment: It's an application event, not a form event. You open the application events file from the project properties. You can use the navigation bar at the top of the code window to create an event handler, just as you can for a form or any other type.